# Not able to connect to public postgres from EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I wanted to connect to a public postgres from my EC2 machine but not able to establish a connection. I have added a outbound rule for postgress port 543 but no luck so far.

Below is the details of the postgress i am trying to connect.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="hh-pgsql-public.ebi.ac.uk",
    database="pfmegrnargs",
    user="reader",
    password="NWDMCE5xdipIjRrp")
```

Also attached is the outbound rule and error message for reference.

[image]

[image]

Appreciate all your help !!

Comment: Can you connect from your local machine (or any other computer on the internet)? I can not `ping` that host. Maybe the host is behind a firewall?

Comment: Yes I am able to connect the database from my local machine....

Comment: And you are not by any chance on the same network as the host, so that your local machine can reach it but ordinary machines on the internet can not?

Comment: No !! From my local machine (ordinarry machine) i am able to connect to the database. But from EC2 i am facing the connection issue.
And it's a public database ideally you should be able to connect as well from your machine unless there is some firewall setting blocking it.

Comment: That should work, it works for me on EC2.  Maybe your instance is running some kind of internal firewall or enhanced security feature that is causing problems.

Comment: How can i check and disable the firewall, can you please help?